# Prisma with Bit.io connection issue

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

I have a next.js app setup with prisma (v3.13) as the ORM. I am testing out [bit.io](https://bit.io/) for db hosting, and I am getting this error when trying to connect with the client. Everything works as intended when I use a local postgres db. I'm currently using a connection string that looks like the following:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://[username]:[password]@db.bit.io/[username]/[dbname]"
```

I am trying to run `prisma db push` and getting the following error

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "eli-front/rankstl", schema "public" at "db.bit.io:5432"

Error: P1000: Authentication failed against database server at `db.bit.io`, the provided database credentials for `(not available)` are not valid.

Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server at `db.bit.io`.
```

I am assuming the core of the issue has to due with the part of the error that says `credentials for '(not available)'` as if something isn't loading correctly.

Using the failing connection string with `psql` works completely fine, but not with prisma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things that need to be done in order for bit.io to work with Prisma.

1. Database names must be formatted as `username.dbname` rather than `username/dbname`. bit.io supports a number of different separator characters in the database name because different clients have different requirements around permissible characters in database names.
2. You have to create a second database on bit.io to use as a "shadow database." By default, this is done automatically—a shadow database is created, used, and deleted. However, most cloud database providers don't allow use of the `CREATE DATABASE`, so a shadow database must be created explicitly. See the [prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database#cloud-hosted-shadow-databases-must-be-created-manually) for details.

See the [bit.io docs](https://docs.bit.io/docs/connecting-via-prisma) on connecting with Prisma for more details on setting up a minimum working connection.